# Windows 10 search is broken

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, windows-search

Since I ever started using windows, my go to method to open pretty much anything is to press the windows key and type whatever I am trying to find/open. However, since last week my windows search just stopped working just look at this:

[image]

I have tried several things I found in this and other forums such as

-Killing cortana

-Running powershell commands such as

`Get-AppXPackage -Name Microsoft.Windows.Cortana | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}`

-Running the "search troubleshooter"

but nothing has changed.

I must say however, that sometimes and very rarely, the windows search do work. But it does like 1 time out of 100 hundred. I am baffled and don't know what else to do.

Comment: Why are you running a command that will enable Cortana if you want search to function, not saying it has anything to do with the reason search isn't working, but it does seem change.  Windows Search and Cortana while linked, Cortana can be disabled, and Windows Search will continue to function.

Comment: If you boot into a minimal boot configuration ( I am not talking about Safe Mode) does search work?

Comment: this website http://home.bt.com/tech-gadgets/computing/has-your-windows-10-start-menu-stopped-working-here-are-four-ways-to-fix-it-11364000314532 has some good suggestions to try out